# On the definition of measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Before exposing the problem we give a series of concepts:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ an algebra of sets and let $\mu_{0}$ a finite and $\sigma$- additive measure.

We denote with $\mathcal{F_\sigma}$ the family all countable unions of sets of $\mathcal{F}$ and with $\mathcal{F_\delta}$ the family all  countable intersection of sets of $\mathcal{F}$.

We extend $\mu_{0}$ to two family $\mathcal{F\sigma}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\delta}$ in the following way:

if $A\in\mathcal{F_{\sigma}}$ 
\begin{equation}
\mu_{1}(A)=\sup\{\mu_{0}(A'), A'\subset A,\; A'\in\mathcal{F}\}
\end{equation}
else if $B\in\mathcal{F_\delta}$
\begin{equation}
\mu_{2}(B)=\inf\{\mu_{0}(B'), B'\supset B,\; B'\in\mathcal{F}\}.
\end{equation}

Now, we give the following definition

A set $M\subset X$ is measurable if for all $\epsilon>0$, exist $A\in\mathcal{F_{\sigma}}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F_\delta}$ such that $B\subset M\subset A$ and such that 
\begin{equation}
\mu_{1}(A)-\mu_{2}(B)<\epsilon.
\end{equation}
The absolute value has been omitted.

The question is: is it reductive to omit tha absolute value?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma$-additive, if $\mathcal F$ is only an algebra?

Comment: @Martin Argentami we suppose that if $\cup_n A_n\in\mathcal{F}$ then....

Comment: @why cant have a longer name $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two different measure!

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: I do not know the book... the lecture notes do not say it

Comment: From the hypotheses you *cannot* have a situation where $\begin{equation}
\mu_{1}(A)-\mu_{2}(B)>\epsilon.\end{equation}$, therefore the absolute value doesn't make any sense. Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Julien why? it seems like a forcing to me

Comment: We guess that $\mu_0(A) \ge 0$ is part of the definition of "measure".  Then we can show: if $B \subseteq A$ then $\mu_{1}(A)-\mu_{2}(B) \ge 0$.  So: we must disallow signed or complex measures in this discussion.

Comment: @Jack: I implicitly assumed that we are not working with signed or complex measures, as noted by GEdgar, which seems obvious to me with respect to the spirit of the definitions... Is your question about what happens for signed or complex measures?

Comment: @GEdgar how can we show that if $B\subset  A$, then $\mu_1(A)>\mu_2(B)$? $\mu_0(A)$ does not make sense, because $\mu_0$ is defined on $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Begin with: if $A' \in

Comment: @Gedgar 
I'm sorry, but I did not understand what you want to tell me

Comment: Begin with: if $A', B' \in \mathcal F$ with $A' \subseteq B'$, then $\mu_0(A') \le \mu_0(B')$.  Next prove: if $A \subseteq B$, then $\mu_2(A)  \le \mu_1(B)$.  Thus you do not need absolute value, since the expression is nonnegative.

Comment: @GEdgar If we suppose that $B'\subseteq A'$, then $\mu_0(B')\le\mu_0(A')$, therefore $inf_{B'\supset B} \mu_0(B')\le sup_{A' \subset A} \mu_0(A')$, from which $\mu_{2}(B)\le\mu_1(A)$. But it can happen that $B'\supset A \supset A'$, how do we do in this case?